# Microsoft Dev Centre accounts

Tags: .net, microsoft, windows-phone-7, windows-8, app

Looks like Microsoft is offering a special offer of 95% of the yearly subscription for the Phone Dev Centre (I didn't say anything about desperate).

What I was wondering is do you need a seperate account to publish to the Windows Phone app centre and the Windows App Centre?

Also I heard some horror stories about the time it takes to get application published on the Windows phone marketplace, does anyone have any experience with this?

[Windows Phone Dev Centre](https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/join)

[Windows App Dev Centre](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/br229512.aspx)

Comment: Microsoft knows the answer to this.

Comment: Already posted on MSDN forums but they are so slow so thought I would post here.

Comment: It looks like they are two different subscriptions; I was able to make two separate registrations, and they both accepted the same "display name," and there are two different prices.  Really, they should have just made this one single store.

Comment: Have to agree with you there Robert. To charge the developer twice to deploy to the different platforms is shocking.

Comment: @Phil isn't that what Apple does also?

Comment: @jschoen - Of course they do.  But Apple can do no wrong.

Comment: Why the down votes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like they are two different subscriptions; I was able to make two separate registrations, and they both accepted the same "display name," and there are two different prices.  Really, they should have just made this one single store.

The Windows Phone App Store is $99 per year, although they say they will credit you back $91 if you apply in the next couple of weeks.  The Windows App Store is $50 per year.

I have no idea how long it takes to get an app approved.  I would imagine that it varies depending on the complexity of the application.

Comment: according to some, not even complexity matters: http://themissingbit.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/windows-8-doesnt-want-your-app-try.html